# Sed is changing the endlines from CRLF to LF

Tags: bash, sed, git-bash, msys

I'm trying to do script to change all occurrences of `xpto` to `abcd` in all `.java` files in windows 10 system. The script is like above and run in git bash:

```bash
$find -path './*/*.java' | xargs -i sed -i 's/xpto/abcd/g' {}
```

But when I got to check the output files, all of them including the files without `xpto` have changed endlines to `LF`. I thought I'd run another script to change the endlines to `CRLF` but in the folder have files with `CRLF` and `LF` and they need to keep the original endline.

**EDIT 1**

For reproduce the problem follow the steps above:

```bash
$printf '%s\r\n' 'first xpto' 'second xpto' > crlf.java
$printf '%s\n' 'first xpto' 'second xpto' > lf.java

$find -path './*.java' | xargs -i sed -i 's/xpto/abcd/g' {}
```

`crlf.java` and `lf.java` files will be with `lf` endlines

Comment: `printf '%s\r\n' 'first line here' 'second line there' | sed -e 's/line/item/' | hexdump -C` is still showing CRLFs as output. Please provide a fully-complete [mre] we can run ourselves to see the change to LFs alone -- nobody but you can inspect your `.java` files.

Comment: I'm also unable to reproduce the issue; `echo 'abcd' > test.java; unix2dos test.java; od -c test.java; find . -name *.java | xargs -i sed -i 's/xxxx/yyyy/g' {}; od -c test.java`; output from both `od -c` calls show a line ending of `\r\n`

Comment: what the point of using `xargs` when you're already using `find`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Really I'm using windows, fixed the tag I'm new in stack overflow, sorry for the mistake

Comment: BTW, Fravadona makes a good point. It won't fix your problem here, but `find . -name '*.java' -exec sed -i 's/xpto/abcd/g' -- {} +` is more efficient and also works correctly with more filenames than your current xargs code does. (To make `find | xargs` be reliable with all possible filenames you need `-print0` on the `find` and `-0` on the `xargs`).

Comment: (also, if you know it'll always be `./*.java`, you don't need `find` or `xargs` at all, and can just run `sed -i 's/xpto/abcd/g' -- ./*.java`, unless the list of filenames is too long to fit on a command line; same thing works for `./*/*.java`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a generic `sed` problem, but rather specifically an issue with with the msys-based version of sed included with the Git for Windows.

One can work around it with some extra logic:

```
find . -name '*.java' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
  IFS= read -r first_line <"$file"
  if [[ $first_line = *$'\r' ]]; then
    is_dos=1
  else
    is_dos=
  fi
  sed -i -e 's/xpto/abcd/g' -- "$file"
  (( is_dos )) && unix2dos "$file"
done
```

Comment: BTW, this is somewhat experimental as posted: I'm _assuming_ that msys won't strip the CR from the file as bash reads from it. That assumption may be wrong, so YMMV; I don't have a Windows machine to test it on.

Comment: This works for me, but added new line in `CRLF` files that didn't ended with blank line

Comment: Ah, right -- that's another difference between DOS and Windows text files (in the UNIX world, all lines are _terminated_ by newlines including the last one; in the Windows world, lines are only _separated_ by newlines). I'm at work right now but might come back and revisit... or do you have `unix2dos` installed? Revising the script to use that iif it detects the input was in DOS format would be the easy fix.

Comment: Nice, I change end of loop to

```bash
sed -i -e 's/getOne/getReferenceById/g' -- "$file"
[[ -n $is_dos ]] && unix2dos $file
```

in end of loop and works perfectly, tks